# Is there a library or framework for geodesic lat/long coordinate calculations?

Tags: math, geolocation, geocoding, core-location, geography

I'm making a core-location driven app where I must calculate lots of things for a given latitude/longitude pair, such as:

- Distance to another lat/long coordinate
- The target lat/long coordinate when traveling a distance x into direction y

Is there something open sourced which can be used?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using CoreLocation, you can use [CoreLocation's distanceFromLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:) as @progrmr points out.

On the other hand, since you specified open source, and that ain't open sourced, you can look at [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) implementations as suggested by @MikeT.

(My original answer, suggesting the Haversine formula, was flawed. As @MikeT points out, the Haversine formula is only valid for spheres. And the Earth is not a perfect sphere.)

Original, flawed answer:

<strike>It sounds like you want the Haversine formula.</strike>

<strike>The [Wikipedia page for the Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) explains what it is and ([at the bottom, under "External links")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#External_links) contains links to many implementations.  I haven't checked, but I have to imagine that at least some of them are open source projects.</strike>

Comment: The Haversine formula is only suitable for calculations on a sphere. The question is looking for library for geodescis, which are usually implied on [an ellipsoid of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid).

Comment: Good point @MikeT. I've updated my answer to include your better suggestions and to mention the flaw in my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some C functions on [github](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/Utils/UtilitiesGeo.h) that does heading from a coordinate pair, or destination coordinates given start and heading.  [Distance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a) between coordinates you can do with CLLocation.

These are based on the Spherical Law of Cosines and derived from the algorithms [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and [here](http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/calculation.html).

Answer (score 1):

[GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) has been implemented in several programming languages, including [Java](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/java/). The library calculates lengths and related mathematical properties of geodesics on ellipsoids of revolution (or spheroid). The calculation errors are generally in the range of micrometers.

To find the distance between two coordinates:

```
GeodesicData g = Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2,
                                        GeodesicMask.DISTANCE);
```

then get `g.s12` for the distance between the two points.

The second example in the question, to project a location given distance and direction, is found using the `Direct` methods.